# Is there a way to prepare a sql statement in prestashop using Db instance?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to find something like PDO methods, that works with Prestashop DB Object, or a module, or new class that uses PDO class and prepare the statements before execution.

If I can change the following by something with PDO class

```
$result = Db::getIntance()->executeS('SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id = '.$id_customer);
```

I didn't see anything like that and I want to know if exists before make more code without prepare statements

Comment: Why do you need that? It works well without it anyway

Comment: Prepared statement is used mainly to avoid SQL injection. There should'nt be a reason to not use it ever if there are parameters in the query.

Comment: I disagree with Daniel Higueras. A prepared statement is used mainly to spped-up a mass insert or whatever, skipping the part where the DB server parses the request to be sure it is valid / see how it could perform joins and other things like that. The parsing is done only once, then the mass query is done without it, thus, faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DbQuery` class for a cleaner code

```
$sql = new DbQuery();
//this line is optional
$sql->select('*');
//PrestaShop will add the prefix to the table
$sql->from('customer');
//or if you want to select specific columns
$sql->select('id_customer, name, etc..');
//each where line is considered as an AND
$sql->where('id = '.(int)$id_customer);
$sql->where('name = '.pSQL('name of customer'));
$result = Db::getIntance()->executeS($sql);
```

Comment: Note that if you look under the hood of the `DbQuery` builder class, it is just a fancy wrapper of weak string concatenation without any of the protection offered by prepared statements. What it does is make the caller code cleaner by providing an interface distinct from implementation. But the fragile implementation did not change behind. Given current PrestaShop documentation still advertises string concatenation as a way to make DB Queries, this is not going to change any time soon.

Comment: @LéaGris Yeah, you have to manually escape the strings and so on. The Addons team validates these when you submit a module. Do you have a better method?

Answer (score 4):

In prestashop you can use ORM like this

```
Db::getInstance()->insert('target_table', array(
'id_target' => (int)$target,
'name'      => pSQL($name),
));
```